# Can I exclude a project or library from breaking on thrown exceptions when debugging?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a solution with about 10 separate projects or libraries. One of the libraries is maintained by someone else.

I've set my preferences (under Debug > Exceptions) to break on selected types of exceptions when thrown (rather than user-unhandled), but I'd like to *not* break when it occurs within this particular library.

I've looked at the Debug tab on the project properties, but there does not seem to be a way to exempt it from breaking on exceptions. Most of the exceptions that occur within this library are handled by try/catch.

I'd like to debug only the project that relies on this library, but not constantly break on exceptions that occur within it. Is there any way I can exclude it from exception breaks?

Comment: can you reference the compiled library instead of including its source code in your solution?

Comment: @Beth I've thought about doing that, but I do sometimes need to look at the source and switching between a compiled version and source version often seems troublesome.